# Is there a way to step-through the code in IRB?

Tags: ruby, irb

```
a    = [1,2]
upto = 4_000_000

while a[-2] + a[-1] < upto
  a << a[-2] + a[-1]
end
```

Take the code above. `a[-2] = 1` and `a[-1] = 2` on the first loop and on the second iteration you get `a[-2] = 2` + `a[-1] = 3`

Is there a way that I can instruct `IRB` to walk through the code. I theorize that doing a sort of **step by step** so to speak can help me (maybe others) a way to visualize *what the code is doing* so that I can get a better understanding of how it functions when I get tripped up.

Comment: After you're comfortable using `puts`, have a look at [ruby-debug](http://object.io/site/2011/getting-to-know-ruby-debugger/).

Comment: ruby-debug where have you been? Post that as an answer and I will accept. @CarySwoveland

Comment: Shortest answer I've given.  Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you're comfortable using `puts`, have a look at [ruby-debug](http://object.io/site/2011/getting-to-know-ruby-debugger/).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to `puts` a value within.

For your Fibonacci sequence, try this:

```
while a[-2] + a[-1] < upto
  a << a[-2] + a[-1]
  puts a
end
```

If you want to go at it one by one, change `while` to `if`.